# How to use CoreFX library code into a standard .Net Framework project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need to reuse the code of one library of CoreFX published at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx into one of my Winforms project.

For example, i need to use `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile

I dont't know if is possible reuse that code to implemt it at my .Net Framework Winforms app. If it can be done, i don't know how to do it. I don't want to create extra dlls, will be good reuse the code into the prject.

I tryed to download the source and place it inside a folder of my project but it did'nt work. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and i'm kinda newbie managin C# projects.

Comment: [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile) is available in .Net Framework 4.5+. Add a Reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` in your Project.

Comment: I need a general solution for reuse any library, nor ZipFile exactly, i used that as example. What i need to use is exactly at this moment is `System.IO.Compression.Brotli` so your proposed solution sadly don't work. Thanks.

Comment: You need [System.Buffers - NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Buffers/) for a Brotli Encoder/Decoder port. Or try with a .Net Standard library [How to reference a .NET Core library in WinForms](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceANETCoreLibraryInWinFormsOrNETStandardExplained.aspx) (long story, sure).

Comment: Seems that the library needs more third party libraries than Buffers or don't know if i'm doing something worng because i couldn't achieve a solution yet.